# Script to unstick VNC keys?

Tags: keyboard, vnc

I've run into dropped key events when connecting via VNC clients, leading to a "stuck key" (usually a meta key like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>) and searching around the common answer on how to solve it is often "press and release each meta key individually until the problem resolves".

However, I've found this to be annoying and time consuming to try and solve it this way. Plus on a bad connection, it sometimes will miss the "key up" event for the meta key again, and still keep the key stuck. So I'm looking for an automated way to do this:

From a script on the client side or the server side, is there a way to trigger "key up" events for all the meta keys (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, and <kbd>WIN</kbd>/<kbd>CMD</kbd>, both Left and Right versions)? Or just a command to release all keys the server thinks are down at the moment? Or some scripted way to at least list which keys the server end *thinks* are down so I know which key to keep pressing and releasing to try and release it?

I've got a Mac on the server end, so a Mac/Linux solution would be needed for my situation.

Comment: You could make a quick AutoHotKey or AutoIt script to send just key-up presses.

Comment: Good idea, though I've got a Mac as the server end, and those are both Windows tools.

Comment: An eaiser way is go to a terminal/applicaiton and press some valid combination of `<metakey>+<key>` where <key> stands for a valid hotkey with meta key combination. Eg: `ctrl+c` Then vnc will get key up

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a server-side solution for my Mac VNC server; create this one-line Applescript, save it as an Application, and run when needed.

```
tell application "System Events" to key up {shift, option, command, control}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the suggestion of Darth Android , this is the [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) **script** I use. It is supposed to release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>WinKey</kbd>:

```
Send {Ctrl Up}
Send {Alt Up}
Send {Shift Up}
Send {LWin Up}
Send {RWin Up}
```

Save it to something like `CtrlAltShiftWinKeyUp.ahk` .

If you have AutoHotKey installed, you can run the `.ahk` file directly. If not, you can **compile** it to `.exe` by using [Ahk2Exe](https://github.com/AutoHotkey/Ahk2Exe) or similar.

Note that this answer is only valid on **Windows** systems. There is some *NIX **compiler** for AutoHotKey scripts out there, but I have not tested them.